# Creating a list of CheckBoxed items across multiple google sheets

Tags: if-statement, checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I'm struggling to find the right formula to do a relatively simple task. I have a google sheet document with multiple sheets that have items listed each with a checkbox. I'd like to have each item that is checked be returned in a separate sheet in order to create a list. I've tried a few VLOOKUP formulas as well as combinations of IF/MATCH logic to get there but nothing seems to be working. Here's what I'm looking at:

[image]

Id like the list to return the "Item Location" for each column with a checked checkbox.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1USgW2iSx_vL3PFUd8UzQlQt0WCOs2gcl3GwGuEYSL-4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER({Sheet1!6:6, Sheet2!6:6}; {Sheet1!2:2, Sheet2!2:2}=TRUE))
```

[image: 0]